# Sonarqube(5.4 / 5.2.1) is not getting started with JDK 7 & mysql 5.2.1

Tags: mysql, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

[image: Image of cmd]
[image: image of db]

> ***I HAVE ATTACHED SOME IMAGES RELATED TO mY Problem***

**Hardware:**

*JDK-7 (Its my requirement)
MySQL 5.7.17
sonarqube5.4 or 5.2.1*

**Process i am following to start sonar:**

1.After downloading sonarqube, i did below configuration ***sonar.properties***

```
sonar.jdbc.username=root
sonar.jdbc.password=root
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
sonar.jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
sonar.jdbc.maxWait=10000
sonar.web.host=localhost
sonar.web.context=/
sonar.web.port=9092
```

- **wrapper.conf**

  ```
  wrapper.java.command=java
  wrapper.java.additional.1=-Djava.awt.headless=true
  wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp
  wrapper.java.classpath.1=../../lib/jsw/*.jar
  wrapper.java.classpath.2=../../lib/*.jar
  wrapper.java.library.path.1=./lib
  wrapper.app.parameter.1=org.sonar.application.App
  wrapper.java.initmemory=3
  wrapper.java.maxmemory=32
  wrapper.console.format=PM
  wrapper.console.loglevel=INFO
  wrapper.logfile=../../logs/sonar.log
  wrapper.logfile.format=M
  wrapper.logfile.loglevel=INFO
  wrapper.syslog.loglevel=NONE
  wrapper.console.title=SonarQube
  wrapper.single_invocation=true
  wrapper.ntservice.name=SonarQube
  wrapper.ntservice.displayname=SonarQube
  wrapper.ntservice.description=SonarQube
  wrapper.ntservice.dependency.1=
  [getting response on cmd in admin mode[![\]\[1\][1]][1]wrapper.ntservice.starttype=AUTO_START
  wrapper.ntservice.interactive=false
  wrapper.disable_restarts=TRUE
  wrapper.ping.timeout=0
  wrapper.shutdown.timeout=3000
  wrapper.jvm_exit.timeout=3000
  ```
- LOG file

  ```
   CreateService failed - The specified service already exists. (0x431)
      Starting the SonarQube service...
      The SonarQube service was launched, but failed to start.
      --> Wrapper Started as Console
      Launching a JVM...
      Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
        Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

      2017.04.06 17:50:53 INFO  app[o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory C:\sonar\sonarqube-5.4\temp
      2017.04.06 17:50:53 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[search]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\sonar\sonarqube-5.4\temp -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer C:\Users\LOKESH~1.KUM\AppData\Local\Temp\sq-process7155234219752233605properties
      2017.04.06 17:50:54 INFO   es[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting search
      2017.04.06 17:50:54 INFO   es[o.s.s.SearchSettings]  Elasticsearch listening on 127.0.0.1:9001
      2017.04.06 17:50:54 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1491481253018] version[1.7.2], pid[9596], build[e43676b/2015-09-14T09:49:53Z]
      2017.04.06 17:50:54 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1491481253018] initializing ...
      2017.04.06 17:50:54 INFO   es[o.e.plugins]  [sonar-1491481253018] loaded [], sites []
      2017.04.06 17:50:55 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.env]  [sonar-1491481253018] using [1] data paths, mounts [[(C:)]], net usable_space [162.2gb], net total_space [221.2gb], types [NTFS]
      2017.04.06 17:50:57 WARN   es[o.e.bootstrap]  JNA not found. native methods will be disabled.
      2017.04.06 17:50:58 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1491481253018] initialized
      2017.04.06 17:50:58 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1491481253018] starting ...
      2017.04.06 17:50:58 INFO   es[o.e.transport]  [sonar-1491481253018] bound_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]}, publish_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]}
      2017.04.06 17:50:58 INFO   es[o.e.discovery]  [sonar-1491481253018] sonarqube/tREKX7ZHS3yCEME6KEmqtg
      2017.04.06 17:51:01 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.service]  [sonar-1491481253018] new_master [sonar-1491481253018][tREKX7ZHS3yCEME6KEmqtg][ntpc01401][inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]]{rack_id=sonar-1491481253018}, reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
      2017.04.06 17:51:01 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1491481253018] started
      2017.04.06 17:51:01 INFO   es[o.e.gateway]  [sonar-1491481253018] recovered [6] indices into cluster_state
      2017.04.06 17:51:05 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[search] is up
      2017.04.06 17:51:05 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx768m -Xms256m -XX:MaxPermSize=160m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\sonar\sonarqube-5.4\temp -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/server/*;C:\sonar\sonarqube-5.4\lib\jdbc\mysql\mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer C:\Users\LOKESH~1.KUM\AppData\Local\Temp\sq-process1860280482306293638properties
      2017.04.06 17:51:06 INFO  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
      2017.04.06 17:51:07 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatContexts] Webapp directory: C:\sonar\sonarqube-5.4\web
      2017.04.06 17:51:07 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-9092"]
      2017.04.06 17:51:07 INFO  web[o.a.t.u.n.NioSelectorPool] Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
      2017.04.06 17:51:10 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerImpl] SonarQube Server / 5.4 / 7b02df9be3cd9448699b5857586e1c6e2b28c007
      2017.04.06 17:51:10 INFO  web[o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
      2017.04.06 17:51:10 INFO  web[o.e.plugins] [sonar-1491481253018] loaded [], sites []
      2017.04.06 17:51:12 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem] SonarQube home: C:\sonar\sonarqube-5.4
      2017.04.06 17:51:13 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin C# / 4.4 / 5b9adce1c37c4ef907b316ea4500ed5d7c4629c4
      2017.04.06 17:51:13 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Git / 1.0 / 9ce9d330c313c296fab051317cc5ad4b26319e07
      2017.04.06 17:51:13 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Java / 3.10 / e55d43e814fd68587a7a9e0f37089492b34445cc
      2017.04.06 17:51:13 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin JavaScript / 2.10 / 88475229068f817583013a08facf2b45d0357829
      2017.04.06 17:51:13 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SVN / 1.2 / d04c3cdb21f48905dd8300d1129ec90281aa6db2
      2017.04.06 17:51:14 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.RailsAppsDeployer] Deploying Ruby on Rails applications
      2017.04.06 17:51:14 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.Platform] DB needs migration, entering safe mode
      2017.04.06 17:51:15 INFO  web[jruby.rack] jruby 1.7.9 (ruby-1.8.7p370) 2013-12-06 87b108a on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0-b147 [Windows 7-amd64]
      2017.04.06 17:51:15 INFO  web[jruby.rack] using a shared (threadsafe!) runtime
      2017.04.06 17:51:37 INFO  web[DbMigration] ==  InitialSchema: migrating ==================================================
      2017.04.06 17:51:37 INFO  web[DbMigration] -- create_table(:projects, {})
      2017.04.06 17:51:37 INFO  web[DbMigration]    -> 0.2160s
      2017.04.06 17:51:37 INFO  web[DbMigration]    -> 0 rows
     017.04.06 17:54:47 INFO  web[DbMigration] ==  IncreaseProjectsNameColumnsSize: migrating ================================
      2017.04.06 17:54:47 INFO  web[DbMigration] ==  IncreaseProjectsNameColumnsSize: migrated (0.1080s) =======================
      2017.04.06 17:54:47 INFO  web[DbMigration] 
      2017.04.06 17:54:53 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.UpdateCenterClient] Update center: http://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties (no proxy)
      2017.04.06 17:54:55 INFO  web[o.s.s.n.NotificationService] Notification service started (delay 60 sec.)
      2017.04.06 17:54:56 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.IndexSynchronizer] Index rules
      2017.04.06 17:54:56 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.IndexSynchronizer] Index activeRules
      2017.04.06 17:54:56 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterMetrics] Register metrics
      2017.04.06 17:54:57 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterDebtModel] Register technical debt model
      2017.04.06 17:54:57 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Register rules
  ```

  A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000000252fbd9, pid=9596, tid=8112

  JRE version: 7.0-b147
  Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (21.0-b17 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
  Problematic frame:
  J  org.apache.lucene.analysis.en.PorterStemFilter.incrementToken()Z

  Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

  An error report file with more information is saved as:
  C:\sonar\sonarqube-5.4\hs_err_pid9596.log

  If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
    http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp

  ```
  2017.04.06 17:55:01 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] is stopping
  2017.04.06 17:55:01 ERROR web[jruby.rack] initialization failed
  org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes were available: [[sonar-1491481253018][tREKX7ZHS3yCEME6KEmqtg][ntpc01401][inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]]{rack_id=sonar-1491481253018}]
      at org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException.wrap(RackInitializationException.java:31) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
      at org.jruby.rack.RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.init(RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.java:98) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
      at org.jruby.rack.RackServletContextListener.contextInitialized(RackServletContextListener.java:50) ~[jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar:na]
      at org.sonar.server.platform.RubyRailsContextListener.contextInitialized(RubyRailsContextListener.java:35) [sonar-server-5.4.jar:na]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0]
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0]
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0]
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0]
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0]
  Caused by: org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes were available: [[sonar-1491481253018][tREKX7ZHS3yCEME6KEmqtg][ntpc01401][inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]]{rack_id=sonar-1491481253018}]
      at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$RetryListener.onFailure(TransportClientNodesService.java:242) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.2.jar:na]
      at org.elasticsearch.action.TransportActionNodeProxy$1.handleException(TransportActionNodeProxy.java:78) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.2.jar:na]
      at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$Adapter$3.run(TransportService.java:468) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.2.jar:na]
      ... 3 common frames omitted
  Caused by: org.elasticsearch.transport.NodeDisconnectedException: [sonar-1491481253018][inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]][indices:data/write/bulk] disconnected
  2017.04.06 17:55:01 INFO  web[o.s.p.StopWatcher] Stopping process
  2017.04.06 17:55:02 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-9092"]
  2017.04.06 17:55:02 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is started
  2017.04.06 17:55:02 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-9092"]
  2017.04.06 17:55:02 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9092
  2017.04.06 17:55:02 INFO  web[o.s.s.n.NotificationService] Notification service stopped
  2017.04.06 17:55:02 WARN  web[o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
   java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
   java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
   com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:43)
  2017.04.06 17:55:02 WARN  web[o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [JRubyJIT-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
   sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
   java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
   java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(Unknown Source)
   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
  2017.04.06 17:55:02 WARN  web[o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [JRubyJIT-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
   sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
   java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
   java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(Unknown Source)
   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
  2017.04.06 17:55:02 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-9092"]
  2017.04.06 17:55:02 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-9092"]
  2017.04.06 17:55:02 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is stopped
  ```

**Strategy I have tried:**

- Created/Deleted Temp folder in *C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local* & then starting service & start sonar  => SAME iSSUE
- clean/delete temp from sonarqube & then run  => SAME iSSUE
- my need is JDK-7 so changed 5.4 / 5.2.1 both => => SAME iSSUE
- ***wrapper.java.command=Gave my jdk/bin/java path*** => SAME iSSUE
- Restarted & Reinstall from scratch => SAME iSSUE

**PLEASE HELP ME,
THANKS IN ADVANCE**

Comment: If this is a fresh install, why would you choose version 5.4? 5.6.6 is the current LTS and 6.3 is the latest version.

Comment: Latest version would require JDK-8, Our project is running on JDK-7

Comment: The JDK you _compile_ with _does not_ have to match the JDK you run SonarQube with, or the one you analyze with

Comment: thanks, but as per sonar documentation , i found this version is compatible with JDK-7
or Else
can you please suggest me a version of sonarqube which is compatible with JDK-7

Comment: The logs seem to be truncated. The EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION you mention is not displayed in any logs. Moreover most of the DB migration steps are missing.

Comment: what are the DB migration steps, could please post any sample. Thanks